# Installing a new dotnet 5 template doesn't work

Tags: .net, .net-5, uno-platform

I was trying to install dotnet 5 template for [UnoApp](https://platform.uno/) and even though it worked on one machine other one seems to just print a list of current templates when I use
`dotnet new --install Uno.ProjectTemplates.Dotnet::3.5.0-dev.270`
command. I use the same OS on both machines (windows 10) and also the same version of dotnet (5.0.301)

Comment: I have the same simptoms. List all template but doesn't install anything. I have Windows 10 Pro 21H1 19043.1083 build.
dotnet version: 5.0.400-preview.21328.4

Comment: I've answered below, but can you indicate where you found this specific command line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the Uno Platform templates is generally done through the [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nventivecorp.uno-platform-addin), and can also be done through the `dotnet new` templates:

```sh
dotnet new -i Uno.ProjectTemplates.Dotnet
```

The command line you use is installing a pretty old version of preview templates. This one installs the latest stable.

Comment: I'm not sure how I fixed it since it was a month ago, but [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nventivecorp.uno-platform-addin) was probably it. Thank you! Dotnet commands didn't seem to work for some reason.